# Batch Script to Rename Files to "Raw.txt" in Subfolders

Tags: batch-file, cmd

Say I have a set of Subfolders, in which I have some files in them (the name of the files does not matter, nor does the file extension). How would I write a batch script to iterate over these subfolders so that I can rename all the files in them to "raw.txt". I have no idea how to approach this, I am only familiar with the "ren" command

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With this command you can iterate recursively over all the files from a give directory:

```
for /r <rootdir> %i in (*) do @ren "%i" raw.txt
```

Be aware that if there is more than one file in a folder `ren` will not change the file's name to raw.txt. Hope it helps.